# Why are SC_HSCROLL and SC_VSCROLL seem to be switched in WM_SYSCOMMAND?

Tags: c++, winapi, scrollbar, spy++, common-controls

I know it's a really old stuff, but I'm wrecking my brain over it. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Say, when the scrollbar mouse click notification is propagated through `WM_NCHITTEST` -> `WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN` -> `WM_SYSCOMMAND` -> `WM_HSCROLL` or `WM_VSCROLL`, all parameters in this chain seem to follow documentation, except `SC_HSCROLL` and `SC_VSCROLL` for [`WM_SYSCOMMAND`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/menurc/wm-syscommand). So if I do:

```
//From within WndProc
if(message == WM_SYSCOMMAND)
{
    UINT uiCmd = wParam & 0xFFF0;
    if(uiCmd == SC_HSCROLL)
    {
        TRACE(L"Horiz scroll\n");
    }
    else if(uiCmd == SC_VSCROLL)
    {
        TRACE(L"Vertical scroll\n");
    }
}
```

I seem to get vertical notification for horizontal and vice versa.

Here's the proof from Spy++. If I click this down arrow:

[image]

these are notifications that window receives:

[image]

All correct except `SC_HSCROLL`. WTF?

Comment: What is that control?  Is that an ordinary Win32 ListBox, ListView, or something custom. Can you post an MVCE (minimal, complete,verifiable exampe).

Comment: Also, what you are really trying to do?  As you can see, the WM_VSCROLL message comes in after the SYSCOMMAND.

Comment: @selbie/: It's a `richedit`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if look for `__int64 OnDwpNcLButtonDown(CThhemeWnd*, THEME_MSG*)` under debugger visible next code:

[image]

```
wParam = HTVSCROLL != HitTest ? SC_VSCROLL : SC_HSCROLL;
SendMessage(*, WM_SYSCOMMAND, (wParam | HitTest), *)
```

the `WM_SYSCOMMAND` with `SC_VSCROLL` or `SC_HSCROLL` sent from this point, but obvious code contain logical error - the `SC_VSCROLL` and `SC_HSCROLL` confused.

correct code must be

```
wParam = HTVSCROLL == HitTest ? SC_VSCROLL : SC_HSCROLL;
```

also

> In **WM_SYSCOMMAND** messages, the four low-order bits of the *wParam*
>   parameter are used internally by the system. To obtain the correct
>   result when testing the value of *wParam*, an application must combine
>   the value 0xFFF0 with the *wParam* value by using the bitwise AND
>   operator.

here visible that in place four low-order bits we have hit test code from [`WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/inputdev/wm-nclbuttondown) message, which is from [`WM_NCHITTEST`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/inputdev/wm-nchittest) message return

`0xf087` - this is `SC_HSCROLL | HTVSCROLL` , when on hscroll we got `0xf076` which is `SC_VSCROLL | HTHSCROLL`

this is simply windows bug in `uxtheme.OnDwpNcLButtonDown`

Comment: Interesting. And it's been there since, idk, Windows XP or so and nobody noticed it? Anyway, thanks for confirming it. I thought I was "seeing things" :) Although, if the bug is in `uxtheme.dll`, does this mean that if the process is not themed, `SC_VSCROLL` and `SC_HSCROLL` will be dispatched correctly?

Comment: @c00000fd - just look this ox xp - the [same error](https://i.imgur.com/7XMuOdM.png).

Comment: @c00000fd - *if the process is not themed* - even not check.. simply need handle `WM_VSCROLL` and `WM_HSCROLL` i think.